# How to configure prettier to check all files with a specific extension

Tags: node.js, typescript, prettier, prettier-eslint

I have installed prettier via

```
yarn add prettier
```

I would like prettier to only format typescript code (I am developing [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-typescript.html) project, there is no `src` folder by convention & there could be typescript files here and there). In other words, I would like prettier to check all files in my project that has extension `*.ts`.

I checked its [documentation for configuration](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html). But there is no such option to specify file extension.

How can I run prettier for only *ts files then? Is it even possible? If not, what could be the workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To exclude files from formatting, create a `.prettierignore` file at the root of your project.

And to format only the `*.ts` files you should ignore everything but the `*.ts` files.

### Example

```
# Ignore everything recursively
*

# But not the .ts files
!*.ts

# Check subdirectories too
!*/
```

In the code above, the `*` means to ignore everything including the subfolders, and the next line `!*.ts` tells the prettier to reverse the previous ignoring of the `.ts` files. The last line `!*/` means to check the subdirectories too, but with the previous rule, it's only looking for the `.ts` files.

Check the [prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) and [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) docs for more information.

Comment: I did that in my .prettierignore. Now prettier ignore everything including *ts files.

Comment: Same issue. It doesn't work. This is what I tried ```!**/*.ts
!*.ts```. Also tried ```!*.ts```

Comment: Modify the ignore all with a forward slash like this `/*`.

Comment: Oh, it works now with your updated answer. But could you please clarify why now it works? I mean isn't `!*/` telling prettier not to ignore all files in subfolders no matter *.ts or not?? since there is no extension specified. I mean how can it guarantee it only checks typescript files in subfolder then? Why `!*/*.ts` doesn't work(I tried) but your answer works.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now understand why your answer works. But I still don't get why `!**/*.ts` doesn't work for subfolders when used as the 3rd line in your answer, do you happen to know the reason too?

Comment: what if I want to format .ts files and .tsx how I can do that

Answer (score 15):

For *.ts files:

```
npx prettier 'src/**/*.ts' --write
```

If you want target other file extensions:

```
npx prettier 'src/**/*.{js,ts,mjs,cjs,json}' --write
```