# configure prettier to check only .ts and .tsx files

Tags: typescript, prettier, prettier-eslint

I have installed prettier via

```
yarn add prettier
```

I would like prettier to only format typescript code. in other words, I would like prettier to check all files in my project that has extension *.ts and *.tsx and ignore the rest of the files cuz I have also .js files and I don't want that to be formatted.

I checked this [How to configure prettier to check all files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715715/how-to-configure-prettier-to-check-all-files-with-a-specific-extension) but it only checks .ts files I want to add .tsx files also.

also when I run `yarn prettier --write .` it formats all types of files in the project I want it as I said only formats .ts and .tsx

Comment: Did you try to add a new line (`!*.tsx`)with the answer you linked?

Comment: yes but when I run `yarn prettier --write .` it formats all files. How I can ensure that prettier configuration is working fine and formats only .ts and .tsx files ?

Comment: you can explicitly pass `prettierignore` with `yarn prettier --write . --ignore-path <YOUR_PATH_TO_prettierignore>`

Comment: I didn't get this `<YOUR_PATH_TO_prettierignore>` what should I write exactly